# Have the model files for the LEGO Sonic head piece been released in LDD or LDraw parts library?

Tags: minifigures, lego-dimensions

I am referring to the "LEGO Dimensions" video game Sonic head piece. I can't seem to find the name of the model, assuming it even exists in these libraries. I've been looking for it everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer half of this question. I have the latest version of LDD and after a thorough examination of the available head pieces, I can report that the Sonic mold has not been added to the parts library. If anyone else here has the latest LDraw parts library, they will be able to answer the other half of this question.

Here is a shot of all the non-standard head molds:

[image]

Comment: Awwww. I see then. I went and looked through LDD & LDraw too, twice each, with no results. I was hoping I looked wrong or missed something. Thanks for reconfirming!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it and i'm using the latest version, now in June 2019.